# Get two simultaneous values in result using Python lambda functions

Tags: python, lambda

I want to get all the points of the circle with equation `x^2 + y^2 = 25`. The value of `x` goes from -5 to 5 in steps of 0.01.

The value of y would be `math.sqrt(25 - x**2)` and `-math.sqrt(25 - x**2)` for each value of `x` at the same time. I am using a lambda function to get the values.

```
lambda x: math.sqrt(25 - x**2)
```

Obviously, it can only the positive values of `y`. How, can I get the negative and positive values simultaneously in the same function?

Thanks.

Comment: @Carcigenicate yes. :)

Comment: Probably not efficiently (unless you used a 2-element numpy array). You could use `lambda x: -math.sqrt(25 - x**2), math.sqrt(25 - x**2)` to return a 2-element tuple, but if you define a function properly with `def ...` then you can avoid calculating the same thing twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a lambda, I'd return a tuple pair:

```
f = lambda x: (math.sqrt(25 - x ** 2), -math.sqrt(25 - x ** 2))
pos, sub = f(3)
print(pos, sub)
```

Although this has the drawback that `sqrt` is being called twice. If you *really* wanted to use a `lambda`, I think you'd need to resort to using an [assignment expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) `:=`:

```
f = lambda x: (ans := math.sqrt(25 - x ** 2), -ans)
```

At this point though, I'd just use a full function, because I don't think this is very readable.

---

Or, just negate at the callsite:

```
f = lambda x: math.sqrt(25 - x ** 2)
pos = f(3)
sub = -pos
```

Which is probably the simplest option unless you're directly passing this function to another function to use that expects a certain format.

Comment: Agree. I see no point in shoe-horning this into a lambda.

Answer (score 3):

You can return a tuple:

```
lambda x: (y := math.sqrt(25 -x**2), -y)
```

Comment: Fine if you have Python 3.8 or above (I think is needed for the walrus)